# Facebook login popup blocked

Tags: facebook, angularjs

I am using a Facebook app to authenticate my users, but if the user is not logged in to Facebook (I am checking it with `FB.getLoginStatus()`) I show him a button to log in with. The problem is that the pop-up gets blocked all the time. I have no idea why, since I am registering the Facebook log in action on `ng-click`.

```
  <button type="button" ng-click="login()">Log in via Facebook</button>

  ...

  $scope.login = function() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    $scope.userId = response.authResponse.userID
                    loginSuccess()
                } else
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            $scope.userId = response.authResponse.userID
                            loginSuccess()
                        } else {
                            alert('You need to log in and authorize the app, otherwise you won\'t be able to take the quiz!')
                        }
                    })
            })
        }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FB.getLoginStatus` should be used on page load to check if the user is authorized and to refresh the User Token. You can use it right after `FB.init` and store the User ID if he is logged in.

`FB.login` must be used directly on user interaction, you are using it in the asynchronous (!) callback function of `FB.getLoginStatus` and not directly when the user clicks on the button.

Example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: In his defence I think one of the basic examples of how the SDK works uses a snippet like the one above to show the shortest viable login code - it's unsuitable for a real app for the reason mentioned in your answer, though